# Firebug or chrome "slow play" or "animated step into"?

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I inherited a large (many files, 20,000+ lines) proprietary front-end/JavaScript library at work.  Is there a Firebug or Chrome feature, dev tool or plug-in that would allow me to "slow play" or automatically and visually step-into the loading/initialization of this large library to help me see how it works and learn it?  Normally, it obviously loads quickly and I can't see anything; I could put a break point or a few in the script and "step into" through it, but that is too slow.  I just had the idea that a dev tool that visually "played" the executing scripts, say, stepping into a line once every tenth of a second could be valuable.  Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is currently no dev tool offering such feature.

For Firebug there's at least a [request for this](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4237). You may want to add your use case there and provide a test case with steps for how you imagine that feature should work exactly.